# Grabbing a single piece of data from a website's HTML and assign it to a variable

Tags: html, excel, vba

I'm working on a project where I grab data that I stored in an excel sheet and search a specific website that can be seen in the code below. Once the website completes the search, I want to grab the "worth" from the top right of the page. I'm fairly new to using VBA with HTML, so I'm not sure how to take the element (worth) that I'm looking for from the web page, and assign it to a variable in VBA so I can paste it into my excel sheet.

Right now I'm able to open IE, insert my data into the search bar of the specific website that I'm using, and click search. What I have is seen below. Thank you in advance!

```
Sub BrowsetoSite()

Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim website As String
Dim i As Integer

i = 2

'Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
website = "https://cardmavin.com/category/football"
IE.navigate website
IE.Visible = False

Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    'assign info to variable to enter into the search bar
Loop

Dim idoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Set idoc = IE.document

Dim Brand As String
Dim Year As String
Dim Num As String
Dim Name As String
Dim search As String
Dim value As Variant

Brand = Range("A" & i).value
Year = Range("B" & i).value
Num = Range("D" & i).value
Name = Range("E" & i).value
search = (Year & " " & Brand & " " & Name & " " & Num)

i=i+1
idoc.getElementById("search-field").value = search
idoc.getElementById("to-mavin").Click
While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop

Dim value As Variant

value = idoc.getElementsByTagName("h4")(0).innerText

MsgBox value
IE.Quit
End Sub
```

The issue that I'm having is the `value = idoc.getElementsByTagName("h4")(0).innerText`. I've tried to get the element a few different ways, but have been unsuccessful so far.

Comment: `Set idoc = IE.document` after you've submitted the search then you get a new page, and you need to get a reference to that new page.  Otherwise you're still trying to access the previous page.  FYI it's useful to be more descriptive about what happens when you run your code (do you get an error?  what is the error you get?) and exactly what you've already tried.

Comment: Can you give an example of the inputs in the cells?. This line `While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE` should be preceded by `Do`. And this line is repeated twice `Dim value As Variant`

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank you for the help. When I run my code, I do not get an error, I couldn't seem to locate the number that I'm looking for. When I add `Debug.Print value` I see that I am retrieving "You'll need a few details:".

Comment: What search value are you using ?  An example would be useful.

Comment: @YasserKhalil An example of the input to be put in the website would be "2008 Topps Thomas DeCoud 436". Also, thank you for pointing those out to me, I must have missed something when copying over.

Comment: @TimWilliams see the above example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `Set idoc = IE.document` after you've submitted the search, to get a reference to that new page. Otherwise you're still trying to access the previous page.

```
i=i+1
idoc.getElementById("search-field").value = search
idoc.getElementById("to-mavin").Click
While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop

Set idoc = IE.document  '<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
Dim value As Variant

value = idoc.getElementById("worthBox") _
            .getElementsByTagName("h4")(0).innerText

MsgBox value
```

Comment: Thank you again. After making this change, it still seems to want to grab the h4 tag from the previous page which will output "You'll need a few details:". Do I need to add anything else to assist in referencing the new page?

Comment: Put a break on the `Set idoc...` line and wait a few seconds - if you continue after that do you get the value you're expecting?

Comment: Yes, I do get it. With that being said, would the best thing to do be to add a delay?

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach. Suppose in cell A1 the string `2008 Topps Thomas DeCoud`

```
Sub Test()
    Const sURL As String = "https://mavin.io/search?q="
    Dim json As Object
    Set json = GetJSONFromHTMLHead(sURL & Application.WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL(Range("A1").Value))
    Debug.Print json("offers")("priceCurrency")
    Debug.Print json("offers")("price")
End Sub

Function GetJSONFromHTMLHead(ByVal sURL As String) As Object
    Dim http As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, re As Object, json As Object
    Set http = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    re.Pattern = "<head>([\s\S]+)<\/head>"
    With http
        .OPEN "Get", sURL, False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = Replace$(Replace$(re.Execute(.responseText)(0), "<head>", "<body>"), "</head>", "</body>")
    End With
    Set json = JSONConverter.ParseJson(html.querySelector("script[type='application/ld+json']").innerHTML)
    Set GetJSONFromHTMLHead = json
End Function
```